# Terminal warning when starting emacs

Tags: fonts, term, linux

If I start emacs from the terminal, emacs will start up with a warning on the terminal:

```
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-courier-medium-r-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
```

I tried starting emacs with `emacs -q`. The warning was still there.

How to solve this problem? Thank you.

(My OS is `Xubuntu 14.04.1`. Emacs version is `24.4.1`.)

Comment: I guess the solution described on [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1896584) may help you

Comment: @IqbalAnsari Thank you. I solved the problem with the [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1896584&p=11544410#post11544410) you posted. Would you like to write that down as an answer to this question? Maybe it will help somebody else with the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution is posted on [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1896584&p=11544410#post11544410). I am posting the answer. The link suggests adding the following to `~/.Xdefaults`

```
emacs*font: 7x14
```

and running the command

```
xrdb -merge ~/.Xdefaults
```